# SASS/Compass: How do I set unique spacing for a single image in my sprite?

Tags: sass

I am using SASS/Compass to automagically generate my sprites. I have set a default spacing for all of the images using:

```
$sprite-spacing:10px;
@import "sprite/*.png";
```

How do I change the spacing for one of the images in my sprite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compass does have a few per-sprite configuration options, and spacing is one of them. You could do:

```
$sprites-home-spacing: 15px;
```

If your sprite map is named `sprites` and your single sprite is named `home`. See the "Options per Sprite" section at http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/customization-options/ for more.

Comment: That's what I discovered but it wasn't working. THen I realized it has to be declared before my import @import "sprite/*.png";